# For int i = value

Tags: c#, loops, search, return-value

I am trying to create some code that search for a value .

As of now the code looks like :

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         uint randBuff = DLL.Extension.ReadUInt32(0x0154d6e4);
         for (int i = 0; i < 144705; i++)
         {
             randBuff = (randBuff + 4);
             listBox1.Items.Add(randBuff.ToString("x8")); 

         }            
     }
```

The value I search is 144705 . The idea is to stop searching for the value when randBuff =144705 . Can this be done with a loop or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: You realize there's no search here, right? And adding 144,705 items to a list box may not be what you wanted to do. That will take a large amount of memory.

Comment: I don't really understand the "search" part. Is `randBuff` an offset that you are increasing by four every iteration? Where is the actual search party (where you check if you have found a matching item)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to search through? You only read that `uint` from the external source once, then you're just slowly incrementing it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, then this is more appropriate of a loop:

```
while (randBuff < 144705) 
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(randBuff.ToString("x8"));
  randBuff += 4;
}
```

Basically, as long randBuff is less than the target value of 144705, add the value to the list box and increase the value by 4.

Comment: Thank you , that was the main idea ! I will try it , but should work . Saved my day .

Comment: That's still 36177 items added to the listbox.
May very well crash.

Comment: @KemoSabe - I gave the answer to what he asked about. Yes, it might crash but that is another issue. Since he commented that it is what he is looking for, I don't deserve a down vote.

Comment: I agree, I didn't down vote you

Comment: @KemoSabe - Sorry, didn't mean to imply that you did